# Combining mysql queries-result across tables

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables; in one table I have the persons information and in another I have the battles of the persons.

To clarify what I mean:

persons_information

```
username
--------
abc
anne
hansgerman
tester
trudiname
hoodie
gabriel
timo
marco
aharon
leandro
hans
benutzer
andreas
```

[image]

battles

```
challenger  opponent
----------------------
tester      hansgerman
tester      trudiname
```

[image]

What I want is, to get all the persons from table1 which are not mentioned as an opponent of tester in table2.

Comment: Thank you anyway for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select distinct * from persons 
left join on battles persons.username=battles.opponent 
where battles.opponent is null
```

Comment: Sadly it did not work, because of my bad english i called the column oponnent instead of opponent, although it did not work.

Comment: Ignoring the syntax error, `distinct *` is either an oxymoron or a tautology, depending upon your point of view

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
SELECT profile.username FROM profile, vs where vs.challenger != "tester" AND vs.oponnent NOT LIKE profile.username
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select persons.username
from persons, battles
where battles.opponent = persons.username AND battles.challenger != 'tester';
```

New code, this should return all users in the persons table that don't appear in the battles table, and also any users in the battles table that don't have tester as their challenger.

```
SELECT username 
FROM persons
WHERE NOT EXISTS  
(  
   SELECT username 
   FROM battles 
   where battles.challenger == 'tester' and battles.username == persons.username
)
```

Comment: Sorry realised my original answer was wrong and have edited it now. This should work!

Comment: My idea is, that the user tester cant ask/get the oponnent if he is allready in a challenge with him, so only the persons in wich are not allready a oponnent of him.

Comment: I understand. this query above should return all the usernames of people that don't have tester down as their challenger in the battles table

Comment: Am I wrong? But with this query you need to have the person allready in the battles table //where battles.opponent = persons.username//
Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: you're correct, my bad, I'm pretty tired :P have edited my answer again!